# dynamic memory allocation

Tags: assembly, c

For dynamic memory allocation in C/C++

```
  int main(){
  MessageBox(0,"crackname","",0);

  int * ptr = new int[50];
  int * ptr2 = new int[50];
  ptr[0] = 0x75;
  ptr[1] = 0x65;
  (*ptr) +1 = 0x75;

  MessageBox(0,"crackname","",0);
  return 0;
  }
```

the assembly for this code is the following:

```
   MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10],EAX
   MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-10]
   MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8],ECX
   MOV EDX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
   MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EDX],75
   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
   MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+4],65
```

Each dynamic memory allocation is 4 bytes. 
But is it possible to make it like this?

```
   MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+1],65   // +1 not +4
```

[image]

And if it's possible, what is the theory behind it with dynamic allocated memory?

Answer (score 1):

int is 4 bytes so when you declare

int *ptr =new int [50]

you have a memory layout like this

```
TYPE   int      int      int      int      int
SIZE    4         4        4       4        4
CONT 00000000 11111111 44444444 88888888 ffffffff
ADDR|00400000|00400004|00400008|0040000C|00400010|
    p        p        p        p        p        p 
    t        t        t        t        t        t
    r        r        r        r        r        r
    [0]      [1]      [2]      [3]      [4]      [5]
```

so you should allocate properly sized memory

char is 1 BYTE 
so char * ptr = new char[50] should work
the memory layout will be

```
TYPE   char     char     char     char     char
SIZE    1         1        1       1        1
CONT    00        11       44      88       ff
ADDR|00400000|00400001|00400002|00400003|00400004|
    p        p        p        p        p        p 
    t        t        t        t        t        t
    r        r        r        r        r        r
    [0]      [1]      [2]      [3]      [4]      [5]
```

if you want to use int only and not char then you may need to employ other 
techniques like ptr[0] = 'sseM'

see code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 0x50
void main (void) {

  int *blah = new int[BUFFSIZE];
  memset(blah,0,BUFFSIZE);
  blah[0] = 'sseM';
  blah[1] = ' ega';
  blah[2] = 'S si';
  blah[3] = 'erce';
  blah[4] = 'oy\0t';

  printf ("%s\n" , (char *)blah);

  char *ptr = new char[BUFFSIZE];
  memset(ptr,0,BUFFSIZE);
  char *foo = "MySecretMessage";
  for(char i =0; i< (char)strlen(foo) ; i++)
  {
    ptr[i] = *foo+i;
    ptr[i+BUFFSIZE/2] = *(foo+i);
  }
  printf ("contents of ptr is %s\nptr[25] is %s\n ", ptr , &ptr[BUFFSIZE/2]);
}
```

executed

```
intptr.exe
Message is Secret
contents of ptr is MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
ptr[25] is MySecretMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

you defined `ptr` as int pointer. int type size is 4 byte in 32-bit intel architecture. thus `(*ptr) +1 = 0x75;` will add 1 to a 32bit mem/reg. maybe you can test type casting like: `(char *)(ptr) +1 = 0x75;`;
additionally memory alignment is 4 just for performance.